# Which units are used for the Print Composer grid?

Tags: qgis, printing

I changed the units on the general tab to inches. When I go to set up the grid under snapping, whats the units. From what I have read it seems as though they are map units, it that correct? I am a attempting to get set up a sheet to fit within en existing title block.

Comment: Seems to me to be the units you set in General

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the snapping grid it is **Millimeters** no matter what as for most of other settings (line width, position and size of items etc - generally most of the settings in QGIS (1.8)). As far as I can see there is only option to change units to inches for page size.

(btw for map frame grid interval/offset - the units are used from project settings - in main QGIS window go to *Settings/Project Properties...* or depending on used projection)